# Install System/Other apps on iphone simulator

Tags: iphone, ios, x86, arm, simulator

By default when we start iPhone simulator it has only few apps installed. 
Is it possible to install other system apps (such as phone, text, map etc) OR or other native apps (such as facebook etc) on my simulator?

Comment: Any updates. Is it possible in 2014?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Nope. Different architectures—native apps are built for an ARM CPU, simulator apps for an x86 one. The binaries are totally incompatible.

Comment: One minor clarification: If someone builds an app for the Simulator you can take the ".app" from the build products directory and install that by dropping it on the Simulator window or using `xcrun simctl install`. You can also send copies of the app to other people to run in their simulator. But you are correct: the build must have simulator slices or the simulator won't be able to run it.

Answer (score 2):

This is not possible at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

This is NOT possible

The Simulator does not run ARM code, ONLY x86 code. Unless you have the raw source code from Apple, you won't see the App Store on the Simulator.

The app you write you will be able to test in the Simulator by running it directly from Xcode even if you don't have a developer account. To test your app on an actual device, you will need to be apart of the Apple Developer program.